# Given the following two assumptions, How to conclude $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}|\nabla g_r(y^{k})|=0 \ $?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Please refer attached 6-page short paper for details.

Let $M(y)=y+2r\nabla g_r(y)$.

Given $\ g_r(M(y^k))>g_r(y^k)+r|\nabla g_r(y^k)|^2, \forall k. \ $ (equation 36 in the paper)

and $ \ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}[g_r(y^{k+1})-g_r(M(y^k))]=0. $ (equation 33 in the paper)

Can anyone tell me how we can conclude $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}|\nabla g_r(y^{k})|=0 \ $?

---

Since there's a gap of index shift between these two equations and the result, I don't understand his logic. The author claimed to also use "$g_r$ bounded above" to reach this conclusion, but I don't see how.

---

Source: Page 561 of *The multiplier method of Hestenes and Powell applied to convex programming*, by R T Rockafellar

http://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr051-MultMethod.pdf

Comment: Please make your question as sell contained as possible.  At least define $M$.

Comment: Ok I updated definition of M.